# Shower faucets still leaking after changing valves

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

I have noticed some leaking from both valves recently and I tried to change the valves (with two like the one pictured). After the change, I was still seeing water leaking from the area shown. I didn't overtighten, and they fit well. The hot/cold valves themselves are hard to turn more than a half turn after they are set (to turn the water on) even when not tightened too hard.

I didn't change the seat, and looking in there, there is a hex looking shape. I have that size to remove it, but it doesn't seem to spin out. It doesn't look like a normal seat that I've seen online, so I wonder if I'm missing something or this is just a old setup. Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know the specific valve, but in a lot of similar valves there would be a rubber washer just to the right of your thumb, to prevent leaking from the valve.  Yours has a white ring in the valve housing, that possibly does that job, I'm not sure.   Can you tell from looking and feeling, what component is *supposed* to seal the valve body?  It won't be just metal on metal.

Comment: @jay613 Thanks. I checked each valve housing and both have a ring, which I just removed and checked. We cleaned and applied those before trying this last time.

Comment: If you mean that the white ring seems like it is supposed to form the seal, and that it is removable, try taking it to a hardware store for a replacement.  Maybe yours is worn out or damaged.  That's a long shot, there is no reason it should wear out but it's easy to try.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a nylon seat. I've seen a few of them. Try again to remove it with your allen wrench turning it counterclockwise. The slightest nick or scratch in the seat will cause a leak.

Comment: Thanks -- I was able to remove that. Pictured here: https://imgur.com/a/QCKGt2b

The one looks a little rougher. Is this something that is still carried at the big name places or will be a special order? Should I swap to a different set up?

Comment: @idlehand It's the top you want to check for smoothnes, that's where the washer on the valve stem sits. You can check the big name places but I prefer a plumbing supply store because they will have them and might recommend brass replacements.  When assembling the valves make sure you tighten them enough.